# 2 products per row vg-rossi theme wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

There are two products in a row by default. Its a theme bug because i tried to change the theme, it displayed 4 items per row. but when i activate ThemeForest template it showed only 2 items per row. I want to display atleast 3 to 4 products per row on shop page.

[image: Check Screenshot]

Comment: Ive edited the question.